# hierarchical clustering with character n-grams in R

Tags: r, text-mining, hierarchical-clustering, n-gram

I have seven texts, and I want to see how (dis)similar they are on the basis of character trigrams.

I have extracted all the character trigrams from each text. So I have seven vectors like this:

```
text1 <- ("aaa", "abc", "bce", "cef", "efg", ...)
text2 <- ("aaa", "abc", "dce", "lmm", ...)
```

etc.

How do I compare the percentage of shared trigrams among each text?

Is there a standard way of creating a distance matrix for character trigrams?

Comment: What do you want to happen in the case of `text1 <- ("a", "b")` and `text2 <- ("a")`? Is this 50%, 100%, or both ('directional')?

Comment: I would think that text2 is a 50% match of text1.

Comment: Is it fair to say you want the `min(percentage-match)`?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I am not sure what the best practice is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reproducible data

```
t1 <- letters[1:10]
t2 <- letters[1:9]
t3 <- letters[1:8]
t4 <- letters[1:7]
```

#### base R solution

```
maxval <- 4   # number of trigram vectors
all.combs <- expand.grid(1:maxval, 1:maxval) %>% setNames(c("A","B"))  # makes all combinations, including self <-> self comparison
```

The following calculates length of `intersect` between vectors and divides by `max(length(v1), length(v2))` for all pairwise combination of vectors

```
P <- sapply(1:nrow(all.combs), function(x) length(intersect(get(paste0("t", all.combs$A[x])), get(paste0("t", all.combs$B[x])))) / max(length(get(paste0("t", all.combs$A[x]))), length(get(paste0("t", all.combs$B[x])))))
```

Convert to matrix

```
M <- matrix(P, ncol=maxval)
```

#### Output

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  1.0 0.9000000 0.8000000 0.7000000
[2,]  0.9 1.0000000 0.8888889 0.7777778
[3,]  0.8 0.8888889 1.0000000 0.8750000
[4,]  0.7 0.7777778 0.8750000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this helped, you can accept answers by clicking on check mark to the left of answers.